# not letting me TAR 155gb images directory, keeps giving me error

Tags: tar

[root@centosvm01 /]# tar -cvfz --exclude=/storage/thumbs/ /storage/storage.tar /storage/
tar: z: Wrote only 6144 of 10240 bytes
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

it's 155GB of just images. I know there is 700GB free on the drive /storage
/storage is a mounted drive.

Comment: Recommend you drop the 'z' switch from your `tar` command. gzip compression doesn't really do much for images.

Comment: Also, is your `/storage` filesystem capable of handling very large (multi-gigabyte) files? Your `tar` command will try to create such a file.

Comment: He's not creating the file in /storage (see answer below).

Comment: Are you still messing around with this? look at the original question and see my response, notice the big number next to it - that's because you'd be done by now if you'd tried.

Comment: i don't see your response. I got it now thank you though!

Comment: the guy below got it working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with your command line.  Look at the error message:

```
tar: z: Wrote only 6144 of 10240 bytes tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Tar is trying to create a file called "z" in your current directory (and is presumably running out of space, which is what this error usually means).  This is happening because the `-f` option takes an argument, so your command line is, effectively, this:

```
tar -cv -f z --exclude=/storage/thumbs/ /storage/storage.tar /storage/
```

When what you mean is:

```
tar -cvz -f /storage/storage.tar --exclude=/storage/thumbs /storage/
```

And of course, as Steve said in his comment, you don't really need `-z` with images, anyway, since they're typically already compressed.